# Como ejecutar una función de JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, whatsapp

estoy intentando enviar un whatsapp usando datos que obtengo en php, html y usando la api de whatsapp, mi problema es que solo ejecuta la función cuando presiono un botón, quiero que se ejecute solo con abrir la pagina.
Este es el código de javascript:

```
<script>
var enviar=document.querySelector('#enviar');
enviar.addEventListener('click', enviarMensaje);
     <?php  require '../generales/id_mayor.php';
        $solicitud_id=id_mayor("solicitud_id","solicitud_de_servicio");?>        

    function enviarMensaje(){
        <?php  require '../generales/id_mayor.php';
        $solicitud_id=id_mayor("solicitud_id","solicitud_de_servicio");?>
        var consecutivo=document.querySelector('#consecutivo').value;
        var solicita=document.querySelector('#solicita').value;
        var nombre=document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
        var mensaje=document.querySelector('#mensaje').value;
        var area=document.querySelector('#area').value
        var cel=document.querySelector('#cel').value;
        
        
        let url="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=52"+cel+"&text=Hola%20soy%20"+solicita+"%20he%20tenido%20un%20problema%20con%20el%20equipo%20"+consecutivo+"%20"+nombre+"%0ALos%20detalles%20son%20los%20siguientes:%20"+mensaje+"%0APuedes%20atender%20esta%20orden%20en%20el%20siguiente%20link:%0Ahttp://localhost/hospital/solicitudes/atender_solicitud.php?solicitud_id=<?php echo $solicitud_id?>";
        window.open(url);

    }
    
    
</script>
```

Este es código de php:

```
 <?php 
function id_mayor($columna_id, $tabla){
                            require '../conexion/database.php';
                            $tabla=trim(strtolower($tabla));
                            $columna_id=trim(strtoupper($columna_id));

                            $sentencia_sql="SELECT MAX(". $columna_id.") FROM ".$tabla." AS ID_MAYOR ;";

                            $consulta=$conexion->prepare("$sentencia_sql");
                            $consulta->execute();
                            foreach($consulta as $mayor){
                                return $mayor["MAX(".$columna_id.")"];///
                            }
                        } 

?>

Tal
```

vez mi pregunta sea muy noob, pero apenas estoy aprendiendo javascript u.u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solución

Todo lo que tienes que hacer es definir la función fuera del *eventListener* de manera que podemos llamar a la función en cualquier parte del script

```
<?php  require '../generales/id_mayor.php';
    $solicitud_id=id_mayor("solicitud_id","solicitud_de_servicio");?>        

function enviarMensaje(){
    <?php  require '../generales/id_mayor.php';
    $solicitud_id=id_mayor("solicitud_id","solicitud_de_servicio");?>
    var consecutivo=document.querySelector('#consecutivo').value;
    var solicita=document.querySelector('#solicita').value;
    var nombre=document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
    var mensaje=document.querySelector('#mensaje').value;
    var area=document.querySelector('#area').value
    var cel=document.querySelector('#cel').value;
}
        
        
let url="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=52"+cel+"&text=Hola%20soy%20"+solicita+"%20he%20tenido%20un%20problema%20con%20el%20equipo%20"+consecutivo+"%20"+nombre+"%0ALos%20detalles%20son%20los%20siguientes:%20"+mensaje+"%0APuedes%20atender%20esta%20orden%20en%20el%20siguiente%20link:%0Ahttp://localhost/hospital/solicitudes/atender_solicitud.php?solicitud_id=<?php echo $solicitud_id?>";

window.open(url);
enviarMensaje();
```

---

#### Entendiendo una función

Una función es una forma de reutilizar código eficazmente, en Javascript, podemos definir funciones de dos maneras

- **Funciones "tradicionales"**

```
function nombre(params) {
    // Código
}
```

Este tipo de funciones son las que vienen acompañando a Javascript desde sus inicios, en tiempos *muy, muy antiguos* solo existían esta forma para declarar funciones

Este tipo de funciones admite el uso de `this`, pero no se considera una buena práctica por lo siguiente

- Su mal empleo puede llevar a almacenar los datos en `window` en vez de en la función

```js
function useThis() {
  return this === window;
}

console.log(useThis());
```

En este caso, `this` es igual a `window` porque no la función no ha sido ejecutada como constructor

```js
function useThis() {
  this.isThis=this === window;
  return this;
}

console.log(new useThis().isThis);
console.log(useThis().isThis);
```

En el ejemplo anterior, la primera condición es evaluada como `false` debido a que la función es interpretada como una clase y en las clases se admite el uso de `this` para referirse a la clase actual, pero definir una clase usando una función **tampoco es una cosa muy recomendable**

La segunda condición es evaluada como `true` porque se ejecuta en el ámbito global, no tiene alcance de `this` todavía

- **Funciones flecha**

```
const nombre = (params) => {
    // Código
};
```

Este tipo de funciones son un poco más modernas, en principio cualquier navegador *exceptuando a IE (porque es IE y compatibilidad 0 ja)* soportaría cualquiera de las dos alternativas, pero se prefiere su uso en casos específicos

```
(a, b) => a + b;
```

```js
const arr = (a, b) => a + b;
console.log(arr(1, 5));
```

Esta función tendría un valor de retorno `a + b`, pues si una función flecha que no tiene llaves va a devolver la expresión

En cambio, si la función luce así

```
(a, b) => {a + b}
```

```js
const arr = (a, b) => {a + b};
console.log(arr(1, 5));
```

El valor de retorno será `undefined`, pues no hacemos un `return` en ninguna parte y las llaves se entienden por el intérprete como una función completa

**IMPORTANTE:** Una función flecha **NO** Admite el uso de `this`

```js
const arrowFunc = () => {
  console.log(this === window);
}

arrowFunc();
```

Dará `true` también si intentas comparar `this` con `window` por fuera de la función

> Como dice MDN: Una función de flecha no posee su propio `this`. Se utiliza el valor `this` del ámbito léxico adjunto; Las funciones de flecha siguen las reglas normales de búsqueda de variables. Entonces, mientras busca `this` que no está presente en el alcance actual, una función de flecha termina encontrando `this` en su alcance adjunto

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba!